# Expression of type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" cannot be used for parameter of type "System.Linq.IQueryable"

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have these two models for MongoDB.Driver:

```
public class Author
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ICollection<string> BooksIds { get; set; } = new HashSet<string>();
}
public class Book
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

And have this query to join the two tables to fetch all data (author and its sub-documents (books):

```
var booksCol = _database.GetCollection<Book>("books").AsQueryable();
var authorsCol = _database.GetCollection<Author>("authors").AsQueryable();

var qry = from author in authorsCol
    let books = from book in booksCol
    where author.BooksIds.Contains(book.Id)
    select book
select new { Parent = author, Childs = books };
```

but I get this exception in response

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[MongoDriverPopulator.Models.Author,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MongoDriverPopulator.Models.Book]]]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[MongoDriverPopulator.Models.Author,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MongoDriverPopulator.Models.Book]]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MongoDriverPopulator.Controllers.Dto] Select[<>f__AnonymousType2`2,Dto](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[MongoDriverPopulator.Models.Author,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MongoDriverPopulator.Models.Book]]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[MongoDriverPopulator.Models.Author,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MongoDriverPopulator.Models.Book]],MongoDriverPopulator.Controllers.Dto]])' (Parameter 'arg0') at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index) at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1) at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression2.Rewrite(Expression instance, IReadOnlyList`1 args) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor) at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Processors.Transformer.Visit(Expression node) at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.Processors.Transformer.Transform(Expression node) at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Prepare(Expression expression) at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Translate(Expression expression) at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Execute(Expression expression) at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.MongoQueryableImpl`2.GetEnumerator() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at MongoDriverPopulator.Controllers.DriverController.GetAuthors() in C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\MongoDriverPopulator\MongoDriverPopulator\Controllers\DriverController.cs:line 63 at lambda_method5(Closure , Object ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

If I retrieve the data in in-memory storage (List) first, then run the same query against it, it works without problems as follows:

```
var booksList = await _booksCollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
var authorsList = await _authorsCllection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
var qry = from author in authorsList
    let books = from book in booksList
    where author.BooksIds.Contains(book.Id)
    select book
select new { Parent = author, Childs = books };
```

Comment: What's with the "select select select" at the end? Just do one select of the thing you actually want?

Comment: I need the super document coupled with its sub-document so I have to select both.

Comment: BTW, If I run the same query against IEnumerable rather than IQuerable it works without problems

Comment: I don't really know what that means. Add the working query to your question.

Comment: I added it......

Comment: your LINQ query should be translated to mongodb MQL, in this particular case it's not possible either because there is no equivalent MQL command or because such translation is not support in LINQ2. You can try: 1. LINQ3 https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/driver/crud/linq3/ which is the newest linq implementation that support more complicated scenarios. 2. Simplify query. 3. Write query in raw MQL command and pass it to Aggregate like: `coll.Aggregate(new [] { BsonDocument.Parse("{ "put here raw mql with $lookup" : 1  }")})`